# RSS Feed in view controller with table view

Tags: ios, xcode, rss

I can't figure out how to implement a slide out menu with a rss feed. Since the rss feed goes into a table view controller.  But I thought about putting a table view in a view controller and then i'll be able to use a rss feed with a bar button to be able to use the slideout menu. But i can't figure out how to put a rss feed in a table view in the view controller. I only find tuts over table view controllers. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will get the data in xml format.you can get the data you need from xml file and store it in a array and reload the tableview in the viewcontroller using reloadData methode.

Comment: Can you show some sample code or do you know any tuts over this.  Kinda confused still. sorry.   How should i write the array and how do i reload the data?

Comment: i think you have to look for a xml parsing tutorial. which will give you all the information you need. all the best